How To Pass a DeviceID with curly brackets as an argument
I am trying to pass a DeviceID into my Powershell script, but it keeps returning as a null value.
The device ID is: {0.0.0.00000000}.{44c76b90-01ce-485c-8705-e93f9be4c435}
When I pass it this way using my script: powershell.exe .\SwitchWindowsAudio.ps1 {0.0.0.00000000}.{44c76b90-01ce-485c-8705-e93f9be4c435} it will say that I have no arguments.
If I encapsulate the device ID using single quotes or double quotes it detects an argument, but I cannot print it to the screen as a script, nor can I utilize it. If I try to run .GetType() or anything against it the program returns that it is a "null-valued expression".
If I run AudioDeviceCmdlets' Get-AudioDevice -ID $args[0] using it, then it does not return a device. I am assuming that the curly brackets are doing something evil to the arguments list. Anyone have any experience with this or know how to pass it correctly?
NOTE: I have also tried escape characters at each curly bracket to no success. This is driving me loopy!
# Include Audio DLL
try {
    Import-Module AudioDeviceCmdlets
}
catch {
    Install-Module -Name AudioDeviceCmdlets
}

# Troubleshooting Area ----------
Write-Host($args[0].GetType())

Write-Host($deviceID)
Write-Host("Arguments passed: " + $args.Count.ToString())
# -------------------------------

# Verify Device ID was passed.
if ($args.Count -lt 1) {
    Write-Host("Not enough arguments were supplied to continue.")
    Write-Host("Example: powershell.exe .\SwitchWindowsAudio.ps1 {0.0.0.00000000}.{44c76b90-01ce-485c-8705-e93f9be4c435}")
    exit 1
}

if ($args.Count -gt 1) {
    Write-Host("Only one argument should be supplied.")
    Write-Host("Example: powershell.exe .\SwitchWindowsAudio.ps1 {0.0.0.00000000}.{44c76b90-01ce-485c-8705-e93f9be4c435}")
    exit 2
}

# Check if valid ID was provided.
try {
    $device = Get-AudioDevice -ID $args[0]
}
catch {
    Write-Host("A valid device ID was not provided.")
    Write-Host("Please check your device ID and try again.")
    exit 3
}

# Set Audio Device
Set-AudioDevice -ID $args[0]


you're missing -f or -File right before .\SwitchWindowsAudio.ps1 and you will need to use quotes to pass this argument

Can you add this as an answer? I've executed 100s, if not 1000s of powershell scripts in command line this way, and I have NEVER used the -f (or -File) specifier. This worked perfectly. Thank you! (I'll mark it as the correct answer)

Happens mainly on powershell.exe, you should use the -File or -f parameter if you're targeting a script and want to pass-in arguments:
powershell -f .\SwitchWindowsAudio.ps1 '{0.0.0.00000000}.{44c76b90-01ce-485c-8705-e93f9be4c435}'

Another alternative that should also work would be (no -f needed here):
powershell ".\SwitchWindowsAudio.ps1 '{0.0.0.00000000}.{44c76b90-01ce-485c-8705-e93f9be4c435}'"

In pwsh.exe (PowerShell 7+) you don't need to specify -f (it's the default parameter there), however in all cases you must quote your argument, this is because { ... } is the syntax for a script block and since you have a dot right after {0.0.0.00000000} it will try to reference a property on the script block ({44c76b90-01ce-485c-8705-e93f9be4c435}) that doesn't exist, thus resulting to $null.

It depends on where you're running it from. Running that command from another powershell requires another set of quotes.  You wouldn't need it from cmd. The default is -command in powershell 5.1. Without the right quoting, it's taken as a scriptblock, or a nonexistent member.
# script.ps1
param ($device)

$device
$device | % gettype

powershell .\script.ps1 "'{000}'"

{000}

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object

